# Why does changing the package name passed to XJC break JAXB generation?

Tags: java, xml, binding, jaxb, xjc

I'm using XJC to generate Java classes from the HTNG Payment Systems schemas, available in the /schemas directory of [this zip](http://collaboration.htng.org/specs/documents/22372/SecureDataProxyArtifacts_FINAL.zip).

If I run XJC without passing the `-p` parameter, generation works fine, and classes are generated under the `org.htng._2009b` package:

```
$ cd schemas
$ xjc -mark-generated -no-header -target 2.1 -npa .
```

All I want to do is change the package name of the generated classes to something more project appropriate, e.g. `com.justin.htng`:

```
$ cd schemas
$ xjc -mark-generated -no-header -target 2.1 -npa -p com.justin.htng .
```

However, doing this breaks JAXB generation spectacularly, throwing collision errors on almost every element.  I can work around this by generating the classes via the first method, and then refactoring them to the `com.justin.htng` package, but that's not very maintainable and doesn't port well to the maven-jaxb2-plugin.

**Can someone explain why this is happening, and if there is a way to work around it with XJC?**  I feel like if JAXB works via the first method, it should work via the second, since all that needs to be done is a simple String substitution for the package name.  I suppose I could use the second method and handle all of the collisions via an .xjb bindings file, but that would be tedious given the number of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I run

```
xjc -mark-generated -no-header -target 2.1 -npa .
```

I get two sets of generated classes, one in the package named `generated` and the other in `org.htng._2009b`.  The `HTNG_CommonTypes.xsd` schema doesn't have a `targetNamespace`, so when it is compiled directly its types will end up in the `generated` package.  But `HTNG_CommonTypes` is also imported by the other schemas, which *do* declare a `targetNamespace`.  When the common types are compiled in the imported case, they end up in `org.htng._2009b`.

Now if you specify the `-p` option to `xjc`, that overrides the namespace-to-package mapping for *all* namespaces, so both the namespaced and non-namespaced types get mapped to the same package, hence the name clashes.

I suspect the correct solution here is simply not to compile the `CommonTypes` schema independently, but only to compile the ones that import it.  The following works for me:

```
xjc -mark-generated -no-header -target 2.1 -npa -p com.justin.htng HTNG_P*.xsd
```

Comment: Thanks, you are correct!  I overlooked the code in the /generated folder (or maybe wrongly assumed it was an intermediate artifact).